# React Native: how to make TouchableOpacity take specific action when user holds it down?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

In my React Native app I have a `TouchableOpacity` that takes a specific action when I click it. But I want it to take a different action if the user holds it down for a second. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recording to the documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches

```js
handlerLongClick = () => {
    console.log('Button pressed long');
};

handlerClick = () => {
    console.log('Button pressed');
};

<TouchableOpacity
    onLongPress={this.handlerLongClick}
    onPress={this.handlerClick}
/>
```